# Business Intelligence in visual studio for Sharepoint SSIS

Tags: business-intelligence

The Business Intelligence option in missing in visual Studio. What I need to install to have this option??

I assume I need to install SQL server full package. But can we achieve the business intelligence through SQL server Express.

Answer (score 0):

To get them in full Visual Studio, you can download and install the templates: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=36843

or with SQL Server Express you can install the advanced services which will include BI Dev Studio (a scaled down VS just for BI development): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248(v=sql.105).aspx

(those links are examples, there are different versions of each for different versions of Visual Studio or SQL Server Express so you might have to search for those)